# Why the data is gotten from service after subscribe is undefined in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services

I defined a interface

```
export interface IEmployee
{
    maNV?:number,
    hoTen?:string,
    gioiTinh?:string,
    ngaySinh?:Date,
    diaChi?:string,
    cmnd?:string,
    sdt?:string,
    luong?:number,
    ngayBatDauLam?:Date,
    maNguoiQuanLy?:number,
    isDelete?:boolean
}
```

I created a file `employee.json` contain information of some employee:

```
[
    {"maNV":1,"hoTen":"nguyen quang du","gioiTinh":"nam","ngaySinh":"03/02/1999","diaChi":"Hà Tây","cmnd":"1131131231231232","sdt":3123123141,"luong":300,"ngayBatDauLam":"03/01/2020","maNguoiQuanLy":1,"isDelete":false},
    {"maNV":2,"hoTen":"nguyen thi duyen","gioiTinh":"nu","ngaySinh":"03/02/1999","diaChi":"Hà Tây","cmnd":"1131131231231232","sdt":3123123141,"luong":300,"ngayBatDauLam":"03/01/2020","maNguoiQuanLy":1,"isDelete":false},
    {"maNV":3,"hoTen":"khuat quang chien","gioiTinh":"nam","ngaySinh":"03/02/1999","diaChi":"Hà Tây","cmnd":"1131131231231232","sdt":3123123141,"luong":300,"ngayBatDauLam":"03/01/2020","maNguoiQuanLy":1,"isDelete":false}


]
```

Then I create a service to get data of employees from `employee.json`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {IEmployee} from './employee/employee'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
  private _url:string="../assets/data/employees.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
  getEmployees():Observable<IEmployee[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

After that I created a component to get data of employees from method `getEmployee()`,the main code like this:

```
  public data:Array<IEmployee>;
  constructor(private service:EmployeeService){}
  ngOnInit():void
  {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(data=>this.data=data) ;
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

I found out `this.data` is `undefined`.I don't know why is  that while I defined it is `Array<IEmployee>`.And help me convert it to type `Array<IEmployee>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are logging the data before it got fetched by the httpClient, keep in mind that the httpClient.get is an async method, if you want you can move console.log to be inside the subscription and it should work correctly:

```
ngOnInit():void
{
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data=data; 
      console.log(this.data);
    }) ;

}
```